# Why is my If-Else statement defaulting to "else"?

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement, time

I'm new to JavaScript and have just been toying with this little IF-ELSE exercise. Essentially, slots 1 thru 4 are static to experiment with the || operator. The const 'testSlot' is one that I've altered as time passes to try and execute the "else if" segment of my code; e.g, if it's 9:10 PM I've 
just been manually changing the getHours to 21 and the getMinutes to 10 and then run the code.

With that said, I can't get either of the first two console.logs to run, it always just runs the "else", which is three.

My question is mostly if my usage the of the date object was wrong or if the syntax in my If-Else statement was wrong. A pointer in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```js
const now = new Date();
const slot1 = now.getHours === 12 && getHours.getMinutes === 1;
const slot2 = now.getHours === 12 && getHours.getMinutes === 2;
const slot3 = now.getHours === 12 && getHours.getMinutes === 3;
const slot4 = now.getHours === 12 && getHours.getMinutes === 4;

const testSlot = now.getHours === 20 && getHours.getMinutes === 34;

if (slot1 || slot2 || slot3 || slot4) { 
  
  console.log('one');
  
} else if (testSlot) {  
  
  console.log('two'); 
  
} else {  
  
  console.log('three');
  
};
```

Comment: `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` are functions. Stupid computers do exactly what you tell them to do and not what you want them to do :)

Comment: Bad: `now.getHours`.  Good: `now.getHours()`.

Comment: Thanks, @Adam and @paulsm4!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.getHours()` and `.getMinutes()` are both **functions** and **require parenthesis** after. Also, `getHours.getMinuets()` wouldn't do anything. You have to do `now.getMinutes()`. I updated your snippet for you. It will still `console.log` three but that's only because all the if statements are false. Wait till its 12:01 and it should say one.

```js
const now = new Date();

const slot1 = now.getHours() === 12 && now.getMinutes() === 1;
const slot2 = now.getHours() === 12 && now.getMinutes() === 2;
const slot3 = now.getHours() === 12 && now.getMinutes() === 3;
const slot4 = now.getHours() === 12 && now.getMinutes() === 4;

console.log(now.getHours());
console.log(now.getMinutes());

const testSlot = now.getHours() === 20 && now.getMinutes() === 34;

if (slot1 || slot2 || slot3 || slot4) { 
  
  console.log('one');
  
} else if (testSlot) {  
  
  console.log('two'); 
  
} else {  
  
  console.log('three');
  
};
```

Comment: @visibleman right thanks! I completely skipped over that. I fixed it

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks so much for your time and these clarifications.

Comment: @JasonB If it helped you, accept it to show others that it works. Not everyone reads comments. People mainly look at if its accepted or not, and the upvotes

Comment: @JasonB no problem. Always glad to help!